# Max solo funciona en una columna query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una query en donde me esta regresando dos valores que aparentemente son iguales en la informacion, de los cuales solo necesito obtener solo un registro
revisando las columnas hay 3 donde tienen informacion diferente les coloque MAX a las 3 para que me devolviera el valor maximo y asi solo obtener un registro
pero solo hacer un MAX de las 3 columnas donde coloco dicha función, como se puede hacer para hacer los 3 MAX en la misma query?

```sql
SELECT   id,
         vn,
         plan,
         hardwaretype,
         serie,
         assoctime,
         status,
         Max(bytestx) bytestx,
         Max(bytesrx) bytesrx,
         ipv4address,
         ipv6address,
         terminals,
         Max(lasttime) lasttime,
         changetime
FROM     terminal
WHERE    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), peticion, 103),103) BETWEEN '25/10/2022' AND      '26/10/2022'
GROUP BY id,
         vn,
         plan,
         hardwaretype,
         serie,
         assoctime,
         status,
         ipv4address,
         ipv6address,
         terminals,
         changetime
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema que tienes? Ya tienes las funciones en la misma consulta.

Comment: que me sigue trayendo dos registros

Comment: Y esperas que nosotros adivinemos por que?

Comment: podes agregar todos los max que quieras.. que pasa cuando agregas los otros max? te tira un error?

Comment: @gbianchi no me genera error, solo que no me regresa solo una fila, como si no estuviera funcionando el MAX

Comment: Eso se puede dar si uno de los campos por los que estas agrupando, tiene un valor distinto, como puede ser que estes agrupando por deviceID y seguramente ese u otro campo tiene un valor diferente.

Comment: @AlexVarela revise y si tengo algunos campos  con valor diferente, como podria aplicar el max a esos campos?, necesitaria quitar el group by?

Comment: Si necesitas solo un registro pues si, pero deberás quitar esos campos del query.

Comment: Tu query tiene demasiados campos.. vos que queres hacer??? y que queres lograr?? asi como esta, no queda claro ni que queres ni que tenes.. el max, devuelve el maximo de un campo... y si devuelve mas de una fila, no es por el max, es porque estas agrupando por cosas que dan mas de un grupo.. estas seguro que querias un group by?

Comment: @gbianchi tengo muchos campos por que es un  reporte, cuando coloco la función MAX en los campos a pesar de tener la funcion me sigue duplicando registros, tal vez es por que tengo otro campo que tiene informacion diferente, el objetivo que tengo es mostrar solo el regsitro que tenga maximo valor en la columna FechaPeticion

Comment: @AlexVarela hay alguna otra forma de que pueda obtener solo un registro, como te decia hay algunos  campos que son diferentes entre mis rows y por eso me muestra 2 veces el mismo registro, pero esto funciona solo para algunos casos, en realidad de toda mi informacion no siempre pueden ser los mismos campos

Comment: Es que esta haciendo lo que le pedis... Group by agrupa por datos iguales.. no va a devolver un campo, va a devolver los grupos de campos iguales.. si un dato difiere, son dos registros...

Comment: Podrias agregar un limit si queres.. pero no tiene sentido..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se puede dar si uno de los campos por los que estas agrupando, tiene un valor distinto, como puede ser que estes agrupando por deviceID y seguramente ese u otro campo tiene un valor diferente. -respuesta correcta de @AlexVarela-